# How should I invoke an asynchronous action in OpenWhisk using API Manager from IBM Bluemix?

Tags: node.js, api, ibm-cloud, openwhisk

I have created a small OpenWhisk action written in Node.js. This action makes a call to a backend system. The function implementing the action follows (I have removed the part of code which is not related with this problem).

```
/**
  *
  * main() will be invoked when you Run This Action.
  *
  */


function main() {

    var request = require("request");

    var data = {
    };

    var options = {
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://whatever.it.is",
        body: data,
        json: true
    };

    request.post(options, function(error,response,body) {
        var data = []; 
        return whisk.done({"msg":data});
    });

    return whisk.async();
}
```

Then I have tried to define an API call in Bluemix API Manager.The call is done. But I receive as a result the Id for the activity and not the contents I returned using whisk.done().

Any ideas?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tldr:** Append `blocking=true` to the query of your URL to return the result of the activation in the same HTTP request.

---

Speaking of action invocations in OpenWhisk there are two different modes you can choose from. **blocking** or **non-blocking**.

**Non-blocking invocations** are the default, where you `POST` your payload against the OpenWhisk backend and get back an *activation id*, under which the results of your invocation (aka *activation*) will be stored. You can get those results at a later point in time (hence **non-blocking**) via the [Activations API](http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/master/core/controller/src/resources/whiskswagger.json#/Activations).

**Blocking invocations** will wait until your activation is finished and return the results *in the same HTTP request*. Blocking requests are made via the same API but with the query parameter `blocking=true` appended.

Your issue sounds like you most likely want a **blocking invocation**. Variations of query parameters can be found at the [OpenWhisk REST API Reference](http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/master/core/controller/src/resources/whiskswagger.json#!/Actions/invokeAction).

Comment: Thanks, markusthoemmes. That solved my problem. I knew about the blocking and non-blocking ... but I did not know that was the origin of my problem.
IMHO, it would be good though that, if you ask for a blocking invocation, the JSON object in the response would return both the activationId and the response.